# Select box: add value as class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form where visitors can select a lettertype; the value of that letterttype is needed to add it as a class; so we can style it in a stylesheet to preview the lettertype.

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide addon-wrap-2094-lettertype-of-text">
<select class="addon addon-select" name="addon-2094-lettertype-of-   text">
<option value="">Select an option...</option>
<option data-price="" value="lucida-callygraphy-1" >Lucida Callygraphy</option>
<option data-price="" value="verdana-2" >Verdana</option>
<option data-price="" value="bakersville-old-face-3" >Bakersville Old Face</option>
</select>   
</p>
```

I have already a javascript

```
$('.addon-select').on('change', function() {
var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); 
$('.product-addon-make-it-personal').addClass($(this).val());
}).change();
```

This javascripts add the value to the div .product-addon-make-it-personal; but there a 2 problems:

- previous class is not beiing removed; there are also other classes in it; so i can't do removeclass in total
- There are more then one .addon-select on the page; can i use the class .addon-wrap-2094-lettertype-of-text of the p-tag above to make sure i trigger on the right select box.

Comment: What are you using the classes for? This is a somewhat fragile and overly complex approach to something that should maybe be done with a data attribute.

Comment: You may add it as a data-* such as `data-letter-type="value"` and you could use `[data-letter-type="value"]` in your `CSS'

Comment: Thanks for answering. The output is generated by a WordPress plugin (WooCommerce extension Add-On), so i have no direct control on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('.addon-select').on('change', function () {
    $(this).find('option').each(function () {
        $('.product-addon-make-it-personal').removeClass(this.value);
    });
    $('.product-addon-make-it-personal').addClass(this.value);
}).change();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39zhqj6s/)**

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Question: there are multiple select boxes with class .addon-select on the page. But it's wrapped in an unique p-tag <ith class .addon-wrap-2094-lettertype-of-text.. Is there a way to see if the select box inside this class is used ?

Comment: then you have to use change event like this **$('.form-row form-row-wide.addon-wrap-2094-lettertype-of-text  select.addon-select').on('change', function () {**

Answer (score 0):

```
var previousClass="";

$('.addon-select').on('change', function() {
//var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').val(); 
$('.product-addon-make-it-personal').removeClass(previousClass).addClass($(this).val());
previousClass=$(this).val();

}).change();
```

Comment: Please always include explanations about how your code works and how it solves the original problem.